Equivalence of knotted spheres in $S^4$
Say we have two smoothly embedded spheres $K, K' \subset S^4$ that are equivalent in the sense that there is a diffeomorphism of pairs $(S^4, K)$ and $(S^4, K')$. Does it follow that they are equivalent in the stronger sense that $K$ is isotopic to $K'$?

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Diff}{Diff}$ The answer is "yes modulo some small potatoes".
There is one case where the answer is a simple no: if $K$ and $K'$ are mirror images of each other you can have a diffeomorphism of pairs $(S^4, K) \to (S^4, K')$ with no isotopy between $K$ and $K'$, precisely when $K$ is not isotopic to its mirror-reverse.
But if you demand the diffeo of $S^4$ is orientation-preserving then the answer is yes.  The idea is you isotope the diffeomorphism so that it is the identity on a hemisphere, and then isotope $K$ so that it lives in that hemi-sphere.  This is an old construction that goes at least as far back as Cerf.  In full generality the theorem states that the diffeomorphism group of $S^n$ has the homotopy-type of $O_{n+1} \times \Diff(D^n)$ where $\Diff(D^n)$ you can think of as the diffeomorphisms of $S^n$ that are the identity on some fixed hemi-sphere, i.e. these are the diffeomorphisms of a disc that are the identity on the boundary (the disc being the other side of the fixed hemi-sphere). i.e. this is a result that is true in all dimensions.
